# Contraction semigroup on Hilbert space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, semigroups-of-operators

I'd like to know whether a certain unbounded operator on a Hilbert space is the generator of a strongly continuous contraction semigroup.
(Such operators are known as [maximally dissipative operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissipative_operator).)

•    Let $A$ be an unbounded **skew-adjoint** operator on $H$.

•    Let $P$ be an unbounded **positive self-adjoint** operator on $H$.

Suppose that $\mathcal D:=\mathcal D(A)\cap \mathcal D(P)$ is a common dense core for $A$ and $P$, and let $A-P$ be the strong sum of $A$ and $-P$ (the closure of $(A-P)|_{\mathcal D}$).

Is $A-P$ the generator of a strongly continuous contraction semigroup on $H$ (i.e., is $A-P$ a maximally dissipative operator)?
Are there reasonable extra assumptions that I could add which would imply that $A-P$ is the generator of a strongly continuous contraction semigroup?

Comment: Isn't that obvious, or am I missing something here? For $x\in D$, we have $\textrm{Re}\langle x, (A-P)x\rangle = -\langle x, Px\rangle\le 0$, as desired, and then we also get the same inequality for the operator closure.

Comment: @ Christian: Yes, the fact that it's dissipative is obvious. The difficulty is in showing that it is maximally dissipative (see Wikipedia page for definitions). Sorry--the first formulation of the question was confusing.

Comment: Let us take a look at the evolution equation, with $A=-iQ$, $Q$ self-adjoint,
$$
\frac{du}{dt}+(P+iQ)u=0, \quad u(0)=u_0.
$$
With $u=e^{-it Q}v$, we have $e^{it Q}$ unitary and 
$$
e^{-it Q}\dot v- iQ e^{-it Q} v+iQe^{-it Q} v+Pe^{-it Q}v=0,\quad\text{ i.e.,}
$$
$$
\dot v+e^{it Q}Pe^{-it Q}v=0.
$$
In the simple case where $P$ and $Q$ commute, then $v= e^{-t P}v(0)$. With $P(t)=e^{it Q}Pe^{-it Q},$
we have
$$
\Vert v(t)\Vert^2+ 2\int_0^t\Vert P^{1/2} e^{-is Q} v(s)\Vert^2 ds=\Vert v(0)\Vert^2.
$$It seems that whenever $[P,iQ]\ge 0$ the situation should not be much different.